# Why is the discrete sum of the inverse of squares greater than the continuous sum of inverse of squares?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I came across this sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{{n}^{2}} = \frac{{\pi}^{2}}{6}$$

This made me wonder about the continuous sum:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{{n}^{2}} \,\Bbb dn = 1$$

However, I was confused to see that the continuous sum is less than the discrete sum. Shouldn’t it be greater as in the continuous sum there are more terms?

Can someone please help me as I am new to sums and integration?
Am I going in the wrong direction or I understood their meanings differently? If so kindly correct me. Thanks

Comment: You are misunderstanding the meaning of the integral. Roughly speaking the summation is the same as and integral with the integrand function given by $\frac{1}{n^2}$ if $x\in [n,n+1)$. If you plot this function you find it is greater than $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Comment: {This}[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence] might also help.

Comment: Your logic proves too much. Every continuous integral of a positive function has "more terms" than any finite sum of positive numbers--or could be split up into more terms than any finite sum--which would imply the absurdity that every continuous integral of a positive function has value $+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the picture in the other answer,

if we have $g(x) > 0$ but $g'(x) < 0,$  then
$$ \int_a^{b+1} \; g(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=a}^b \;  g(j) \; < \; \int_{a-1}^b \;  g(x) \; dx   $$

or, starting the sum at $2$

$$ \int_2^\infty \; \frac{1}{x^2} \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{n=2}^\infty \; \frac{1}{n^2} \; < \; \int_{1}^\infty \;   \frac{1}{x^2} \; dx   $$

I learned how to make the appropriate diagram from Rivers,  below you can see how the integral from $1$  is bigger than the sum starting at $2$

[image]

so

$$  \; \frac{1}{2} \;   \;  < \; \sum_{n=2}^\infty \; \frac{1}{n^2} \; < \; 1   $$
and
$$  \; \frac{3}{2} \;   \;  < \; \sum_{n=1}^\infty \; \frac{1}{n^2} \; < \; 2   $$

We can reduce a source of error by integrating at the half integer points,  where we get an approximation but not explicit inequalities:   the sum starting at $2$  is approximately the integral beginning at $\frac{3}{2}$

so

$$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \; \frac{1}{n^2} \; \approx  \; \frac{2}{3}   $$

and

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \; \frac{1}{n^2} \; \approx  \; \frac{5}{3}   $$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 7):

Proof without words.
The discrete sum is the red area in the graph; the continuous integral is the blue area in the graph.
Clearly the red area strictly exceeds the blue area.
[image]

Comment: Hi, how does one get your diagram, I guess it is in Desmos?

Comment: Yep, it's Desmos. You can see what I typed in to get the shadings, as well.

Comment: Got the first one already. Thank you!

Comment: Finally got what I wanted,  diagram for the inequalities in the other direction